# How to use destructuring and assignment syntax to make immutable copy of object with different key names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using destructuring and assignment syntax to make a copy of an object with different key names.

```
const {
    currHash: password,
    lastLog: lastLoginDate,
    userID: userName,
} = oldObj;

const newObj = {
    password,
    lastLoginDate,
    userName,
};
```

I know there are a lot of other ways to get this same result, functions, iterations, etc. But I'm wondering if it is possible to do it this way in one step?

Comment: Why not put it in the new object literal? `newObj = { password: oldObj.password }`

Comment: You could also use a comma instead of two separate statements - but yeah, I'd avoid destructuring entirely here.

Comment: Destructuring is for extracting object or array elements into separate variables, it's not for creating new objects.

Comment: If you want to make a copy of an object but rename the properties, I suggest you define a function to do it.

Comment: Then you can do `const newObj = rename_props(oldObj, {
    currHash: password,
    lastLog: lastLoginDate,
    userID: userName,
});`

Comment: Yes, I will probably use a function or something similar. I was just wondering if it was possible.